# AWS Elastic Beanstalk high availbility mode DNS A record issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node.js app hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk in high availability mode (i.e., it uses a load balancer). My challenge is that my domain is hosted elsewhere, and the Elastic Beanstalk instance in high availability mode doesn't seem to use an IP address; instead, it gives you an AWS domain URL, which my hosting provider does not accept as an A record. From my understanding, the load balancer is not meant to use an IP address, but my hosting only allows IP addresses to be used in its A records. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The hosting provider of your domain name should probably allows you to set CNAME records. A [CNAME](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enregistrement_de_nom_canonique) is the solution in this case.

If you cannot use a CNAME record, the solution is very complicated, because the load balancer of ElasticBeanstalk (Application Load Balancer) cannot have its own IP public. In this case, a solution could be to add a Network Load Balancer in front of the Application Load Balancer, because it can dispose of IP public. But if you can avoid it, it's better.

Comment: Was this answer helpfull ? If yes, please consider accepting it or upvoting. Thank you